# Wordpress multisite .../en is forwarded to .../engineering - any ideas?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

It seems that the address is being completed automatically but I want to get the content of .../en and not of .../engineering
Any ideas?
Cheers
Tristan

Comment: Do you have a multisite named /en ?

Comment: yes there is the "main" domain says http://mydomain and there is the English Version of it and the content is under http://mydomain/en

Comment: I think this may have something to do with it: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71927/how-to-prevent-automatic-redirection

Comment: Nikolay's link will help you out. When you input a URL into a WP site that doesn't resolve to a page/post and would otherwise generate a 404 error, WP attempts to find the page in the database based on what you entered. If it find a "match" it will redirect you. You can disable the behaviour with a WP filter. Check the link above.

Comment: Great, thanks! Cheers